# Ruby: What is the best approach to deprecate just one argument of a method?

Tags: ruby

Considering a class with a method that used to receive 2 arguments but now on the new versions the argument is not anymore wanted. What is the best approach to deprecate this method's argument?

The Ruby stdlib has a `deprecate` method that would deprecate the entire method, but I still want the method to exist, it just don't need one of the arguments it used to receive, and was already an optional argument.

And example would be

```rb
class DateValidator
  def date_valid?(date_string, fmt="%Y-%m-%d")
    # any check that does not even look for `_fmt` anymore
  end
```

If I simply deprecate this method, a deprecation warning will be sent even when someone call the method without passing the second argument.

I want to change the method arity soon to explicitly ommit the argument, but I want do that in a new version, and I don't want break compatibility with the classes that still passes the second argument, even if it is not necessary anymore.

So, how would be the best approach to warn of the deprecation of the 2nd argument in this example?

Comment: Default the `fmt` argument to nil, and if it's given show a warning.

Comment: @maxpleaner that is really a good point... simple but right on the mark! Would you mind put your comment as an answer? 
Otherwise I will not be able to mark the question as answered

Comment: What class has a method `deprecate`?

Comment: Allowing the new method to be called with two arguments, in which case you would disregard one and issue a warning, is an ugly and potentially dangerous kludge. The safest approach is to accept only one argument, allowing an exception to be raised if an attempt is made to pass two arguments, and track down and fix the parts of your entire code base that presently call the method with two arguments.  Note that a warning can be easily missed if it's just one message among many.

Comment: I could make an answer, it's very simple, but I am wondering why you want to deprecate it. The second argument is already optional (it has a default value) so calling it with 1 or 2 args would still work. Unless you really don't want to allow the user to specify this value.

Comment: @CarySwoveland deprecate comfes from the module Gem::Deprecate from stdlib/rubygems

Comment: @maxpleaner the deprecations is to alert that the argument is not anymore being used and should be gone on subsequent versions
Let the argument there and never use it, is something possible but maybe not desired for long... Imagine maintain for years an argument that is not needed.
While remove all of a sudden the argument, may break compatibility with systems that currently use the gem without alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the second argument is provided like so:

```
  def date_valid?(date_string, fmt=nil)
    if fmt
      warn "second argument to `date_valid?` is deprecated (#{caller[-2]})"
    end
    fmt ||= "default value"
    # ... 
  end
```

But like I mentioned in a comment, not sure why you would want to deprecate the second argument at all (it is optional, after all), unless it's important that the user *not* customize this value

Comment: the intention is make clear that the argument that once was optional, now is not even used anymore.

Comment: the check if it was passed and send a `warn` will work pretty much... then in future major release the second argument will be completely removed.

Comment: I'm just looking for a smooth integration between parts... with an approach like "Instruct in the right direction" with a warning on a current release, and then "punish" raising exception in a major release